# Operator "&&" cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

Tags: c#

I dont know what is the different these two code. Above only have single `&` while below have `&&`. I have an error for the above code. I dont how to solve it.

```
Cmd3[8] = (byte)(Length & 0xFF);
Cmd3[9] = (byte)(((Length >> 8) && 0xFF) ? -1 : 0);
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: You should use `&` (**bitwise** and)

Comment: `&&` is a **logical and** while `&` is a **binary and**. (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sbf85k1c.aspx)

Comment: `&&` you can translate to english `and` while single `&` is **bitwise and operator**

Answer (score 2):

You, probably, mean *bitwise* And: `&`; another issue is that unlike *C*, *C#* doesn't implicitly convert integer `0` into `bool` `false`, and, finally, `(byte) -1` conversion can cause `OverflowException`:

```
// since -1 is out of byte range and you don't want exception to be thrown
// you have to (in general case) put "unchecked" to allow integer overflow 
unchecked { 
  ...
  Cmd3[8] = (byte)(Length & 0xFF);
  // != 0: C# can't convert int 0 into bool false
  // &:    bitwise And (not logical one)
  Cmd3[9] = (byte)(((Length >> 8) & 0xFF) != 0 ? -1 : 0); // -1 can cause integer overflow
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that a single `&` is a bitwise AND, while `&&` is a boolean operator (which can only be applied to boolean operands). 
You probably want the code to use single `&`.